# Date and time format (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm) with regexp flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like the date to be in this form dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm and the date shold be a valid date when I put that in the inputFormatters of the ReactiveTextField I can't write anything

```
FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(
          r'(([012][0-9])|(3[01]))\/([0]{0,1}[1-9]|1[012])\/\d{4} ([01][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([01345][0-9])'))

Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: ReactiveTextField(
                        //maxLength: maxLengthConst15,
                      valueAccessor: DateTimeValueAccessor(
                          dateTimeFormat: DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm')),
                      inputFormatters: [
                       FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(
                           r'(([012][0-9])|(3[01]))\/([0]{0,1}[1-9]|1[012])\/\d{4} ([01][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([01345][0-9])')),
                     
                      ],
                      formControl: formModel.dateControl,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          labelText:
                              "Date"),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: Maybe when using `inputFormatters`, it will only allow the input to be a full date in a single change. I think you may only need a validator. In `inputFormatters`, you can add some simple keystroke check, like `[0-9:/\s]`. And it would be better to show your format in the placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `validator` inside `TextFormField`. **Firstly**, you have to create `controller` for your `TextFormField`.

```
 static final RegExp sampleRegex = RegExp(
          r'(([012][0-9])|(3[01]))\/([0]{0,1}[1-9]|1[012])\/\d{4} ([01][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([01345][0-9])');

validator: (value) {
   if (sampleRegex.hasMatch(_dateController.text)) {
                        return "Try again";
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
```

Comment: I use the reactiveTextField and I don't have the validator, so I can't do this

Comment: In this case, you have to  make sure that your regex is working or not, if it works, you have to use normal textformfield instead to achieve desired functionality